# Oracle SQL Erro Invalid Number

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho a query abaixo, que me mostra data e horário, gravado como padrão `sysdate` do Oracle:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATA, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:SS') D1, 
       TO_CHAR(DATA_FIM, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:SS') D2 
FROM 
       PCN_ROMANEIO_CHECK 
WHERE ROMANEIO = '1234567'
```

Com o resultado:

```
26/08/2016 10:52:37 26/08/2016 10:53:55
```

Acontece que, se eu tento calcular a diferença entre ambas ocorre o erro de `Invalid Number.`

Sei que o motivo é a transformação deles em CHAR, mas existe alguma forma que poderia fazer essa diferença dessas datas diretamente na query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Você pode subtrair datas em Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096853/calculate-difference-between-2-date-times-in-oracle-sql). Isto lhe dará a diferença em dias. Multiplicar por 24 para obter horas, e assim por diante.

```
SQL> select oldest - creation from my_table;
```

Se a sua data é armazenada como dados de caracteres, você tem que convertê-lo para um tipo de data em primeiro lugar.

```
SQL> select 24 * (to_date('2009-07-07 22:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi') 
             - to_date('2009-07-07 19:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')) diff_hours 
       from dual;

DIFF_HOURS
----------
       2.5
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Tentei adaptar para meu caso, mas não deu certo, trouxe zero no resultado.

Comment: @Diego, você tem que adaptar para retorna em minutos, a resposta esta em horas 24 * ( ...